# How to fix my non-starting little game app?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have to do a little game for my school, and I'm stuck in my program. When I launch the app it's working fine, but when I want to start a new game by the menubar, it says that the game is starting, but it isn't. I think the program is stuck in my FenRPS::newGame() function, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
FenRPS::FenRPS() : wxFrame( NULL, wxID_ANY, "Rock–paper–scissors", 
wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(607,650), wxCAPTION|wxCLOSE_BOX|wxCLIP_CHILDREN )
{
  this->SetBackgroundColour( wxColor( 240,240,240 ));
  this->SetIcon( wxIcon( AppRPS::Icone_xpm ));

  //================ MENU ================
  wxMenuItem*  item;

  #define Item( menu, fctEvenement, texte, aide )                  \
      item = menu->Append( wxID_ANY, texte, aide );                \
      menu->Bind( wxEVT_MENU, fctEvenement, this, item->GetId() );
  #define Separateur( menu )    menu->AppendSeparator();

  menuGame = new wxMenu;
    Item( menuGame, newGame, "&New Game", "Create a new game" );
    Separateur( menuGame );
    Item( menuGame, exit, "Exit", "Exit the game" );
  menuAbout = new wxMenu;
    Item( menuAbout, about, "&About", "Display app informations" );

  menuBar = new wxMenuBar;
  menuBar->Append( menuGame, "&Game" );
  menuBar->Append( menuAbout, "&About" );
  this->SetMenuBar( menuBar );

  //=============== BOUTONS ==============
  rock_png = new wxStaticBitmap(this, wxID_ANY, wxBitmap("img/rock.png", 
wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG), wxPoint(54,400), wxSize(128,128));
    buttonRock.Create( this, wxID_ANY, "R O C K", wxPoint(54,538), wxSize(128,50));
    buttonRock.Bind( wxEVT_BUTTON, playedRock, this );
  paper_png = new wxStaticBitmap(this, wxID_ANY, 
wxBitmap("img/paper.png", wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG), wxPoint(236,400), wxSize(128,128));
    buttonPaper.Create( this, wxID_ANY, "P A P E R", wxPoint(236,538), wxSize(128,50));
    buttonPaper.Bind( wxEVT_BUTTON, playedPaper, this );
  scissors_png = new wxStaticBitmap(this, wxID_ANY, 
wxBitmap("img/scissors.png", wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG), wxPoint(418,400), wxSize(128,128));
    buttonScissors.Create( this, wxID_ANY, "S C I S S O R S", wxPoint(418,538), wxSize(128,50));
    buttonScissors.Bind( wxEVT_BUTTON, playedScissors, this );

  stTextBox = new wxStaticText;
 stTextBox->Create( this, wxID_ANY, "\nWelcome in the Rock-Paper-Scissors game\n\n\n\nNo game is in progress", wxPoint(10,10), wxSize(580,364), wxALIGN_CENTRE_HORIZONTAL);
  stTextBox->SetBackgroundColour( *wxLIGHT_GREY );
  stTextBox->SetFont( wxFont( wxFontInfo(12).FaceName("Arial").Bold()));

  if( hasPlayed )
  {
    srand(time(0));
    choiceBot = (rand()%3)+1;
    message << "Round n°" << nbrRound << "\n";
    stTextBox->SetLabel( message );

    if (choicePlayer == 1 && choiceBot == 1) message << message << "Equality\n\n\n";
   else if (choicePlayer == 1 && choiceBot == 2)
   {
        message << message << "Round lost, the bot has made 'paper'\n\n\n";
    scoreBot++;
}
else if (choicePlayer == 1 && choiceBot == 3)
{
    message << message << "Round win, the bot had made 'scissors'\n\n\n";
    scorePlayer++;
}
else if (choicePlayer == 2 && choiceBot == 1)
{
    message << message << "Round win, the bot had made 'rock'\n\n\n";
    scorePlayer++;
}
else if (choicePlayer == 2 && choiceBot == 2) message << message << "Equality\n\n\n";
else if (choicePlayer == 2 && choiceBot == 3)
{
    message << message << "Round lost, the bot has made 'scissors'\n\n\n";
    scoreBot++;
}
else if (choicePlayer == 3 && choiceBot == 1)
{
    message << message << "Round lost, the bot has made 'rock'\n\n\n";
    scoreBot++;
}
else if (choicePlayer == 3 && choiceBot == 2)
{
    message << message << "Round win, the bot had made 'paper'\n\n\n";
    scorePlayer++;
}
else if (choicePlayer == 3 && choiceBot == 3) message << message << "Equality\n\n\n";
stTextBox->SetLabel( message );
nbrRound++;
hasPlayed = false;
}

  if( nbrRound > 5 )
  {
    message << "The game is over\n\n"
        << "Score :\n"
        << ">> Player     : " << scorePlayer
        << "\n>> Computer : " << scoreBot;
if (scoreBot == scorePlayer)
    message << message << "Equality. Try again\n";
else if (scoreBot > scorePlayer)
    message << message << "You lost, you'll be luckier next time\n";
else if (scorePlayer > scoreBot)
    message << message << "You won, congratulations !\n";
stTextBox->SetLabel( message );
wxSleep(2);
  }
}

FenRPS::~FenRPS() {}

void FenRPS::playedRock( wxCommandEvent& )     { choicePlayer = 1; hasPlayed = true; }
void FenRPS::playedPaper( wxCommandEvent& )    { choicePlayer = 2; hasPlayed = true; }
void FenRPS::playedScissors( wxCommandEvent& ) { choicePlayer = 3; hasPlayed = true; }
void FenRPS::newGame( wxCommandEvent& )
{
  stTextBox->SetLabel( "\nThe game is starting..." );
}
```

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger will help you step through your program and allows you to *watch* values in variables.  Often, using a debugger is faster than posting to StackOverflow and waiting for somebody to inspect or debug your program for you.

Comment: If you are allergic to debuggers, you may want to implement a *log file*.  Open a file and print to it at various points in your program (printing to the console with a windowing program is a little more difficult).  You may want to prefix the log messages with a time stamp.

Comment: I recommend using nested `switch` statements.  IMHO, processing menu selections with `switch` is more readable.  Easy to read programs have fewer defects.

Comment: When the User selects the menu item `New Game`, the framework calls `FenRPS::newGame`.  Your `newGame()` method sets the text in a label and returns, *nothing else happens*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the game playing code out of the `wxFrame` constructor and into the `newGame()` event handler.

The `wxFrame` constructor is called once, when creating the window (frame).  The primary purpose of this constructor is to place all the widgets and initialize them.

When the User selects "New Game" from the Menu, the Menu object sends out an event.  Your `newGame()` method is set up to receive this event.  Thus, your program should have code in this method to create and and start a new game.